# Can Goku and Vegeta attain Super Saiyan Rose?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

I know that *apparently* there is no information about this in the Dragon Ball Super series.

But since new information is constantly popping up in manga, magazines, etc. Before the series sometimes, that's why I'm asking.

More data on this, according to [Dragon Ball Wikia on Super Saiyan Rosé](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Ros%C3%A9)

> This form is a counterpart to Super Saiyan Blue, and possesses a
>   different hair color due to the user already possessing the status as
>   a god prior to surpassing Super Saiyan God

So if Goku would turn a god of destruction as when he was offered once (or Vegeta) or Trunks would become a Kaioshin as when he was a Kaioshin apprentice, wouldnt they turn into Super Saiyan Rosé when trying to transform into super saiyan god super saiyan?

Comment: Honestly, it appears to just be the alternate universe version of SSGSS.

Comment: That's what I was wondering too, if it has some paralel with the regular saiyan transformations

Comment: But Black in base appears to be so strong, he could give fight to Vegita in Blue

Comment: May be it's an alternative version of some lower regular saiyajin transformation

Comment: And Goku had to turn to SSJ2 to be a match for Black in base form

Comment: Black is stronger. This is a given. He's clearly from some sort of stronger Evil universe. But everything is color swapped -- except Black himself, apparently.  This includes his universe's Supreme Kai.

Comment: I don't understand the questions that come up *hours* after an episode/chapter of a series come out. Unless the author is a diligent contributor to anime.stackexchange, I would suggest you just **wait and see**

Comment: super saiyan rainbow maybe

Comment: @solalito hard do know why you dont understand, with all the hundreds to thousands videos with questions like this one out there. As a matter of fact, videos who predicted the super saiyan rose are talking about black being a being created by zamazu . If it's pure speculation or based in some magazine, interview or leaked information from japan, I dont know, but it might be answered very soon.

Comment: @Pablo My point was that this would more likely trigger some kind of debate instead of generating an answers backed up by facts. Therefore, I think it would be more appropriate as a forum thread than as a post on this website.

Comment: Next time on Dragon Ball Z : Explode! Super Saiyan Emerald!

Comment: Super Saiyan Rosé is not an alternate universe form, it is a God (that happens to be Saiyan) achieving Super Saiyan..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think they would be able to achieve it because I think it is partly linked to him being the same kind of race as Gowasu (as in mind)

Comment: That's a fair statement. But uh.Any idea what race Gowasu actually is? I feel like this going to turn into another one of those "Freeza's race" and "Recoome's race" things again.

Comment: @KazRodgers Gowasu is a Shinjin as the wiki calls it, and all Kais (our own North Kai called King Kai, to Shin the Supreme Kai and his attendant Kibito) are as well. The fun part is that they are born from the Fruit of a special and specific tree, and the Supreme kais and those like Gowasu, Shin, and Zamasu are special golden fruits who are stronger and have significantly longer life spans (75k years for those like King Kai and Kibito vs 5 million for Shin, Zamasu and Gowasu) http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Shinjin

Answer (score 1):

Super Saiyan Rose is Goku Black's version of the regular Super Saiyan that surpassed the power of Super Saiyan God and evolved naturally into SSGSS/A differently colored Super Saiyan Blue due to his status as an actual god with natural god ki.SSGSS is blue for Goku and Vegeta because they aren't actual gods just mortals with godly ki.

Answer (score 0):

This transformation has something to do with Zamasu being inside of Goku.

Example:

In DBGT Baby took Vegeta's body and transformed into super saiyan and Baby Vegeta's hair was white. For what I know Goku and Vegeta will not get this transformation because Zamasu is a "World King God" from Universe 10 and Zamasu being a god being inside of goku made a mutated transformation like Baby in DBGT

Answer (score -2):

Don't listen to anyone else except Zamasu it has to do with the fact that Super Saiyan Rose is Goku Black's version of the regular Super Saiyan that surpassed the power of Super Saiyan God and evolved naturally into SSGSS/A differently colored Super Saiyan Blue due to his status as an actual god with natural god ki. SSGSS is blue for Goku and Vegeta because they aren't actual gods just mortals with godly ki.

Comment: Do you have any references/sources to support your answer?